# Access localhost on windows

Tags: django, windows, localhost

I am running on a Windows 64 bits machine. I cannot access any process running on my localhost, for example:
I tried to launch a django project, everything seems to work fine.

> python manage.py runserver

[Django server works fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhA8u.png)

but when I launch a client, I keep waiting but nothing happens.
Same goes with Node JS and Wild-fly server .
I tried to run the servers using administrative privileges but nothing seems to fix it.

Comment: Please post text as, y'know, text. Pretty darn impossible to perform a text search against a PNG.

Comment: Try to add the full trace back while you are accessing the application on the browser.

Comment: what do you mean by launching a client? as in browser or something? Also what do you mean by accessing processes running on localhost?

Comment: exactly.it was just an example, i have two projects one is django based the other is node based. they both run well in other machines. and i can't even publish mqtt message nor receive. the problem is in my computer, i can't send messages to any server, i had to mention that the internet connection works just fine and didn't have problem with internet navigation. i guess it has something todo with my windows configuration or the process that are running on it.

Answer (score 0):

Its seems like you have un-applied migrations that you haven't applied. Try to run `python manage.py migrate`.

Comment: it was just an example, i have two projects one is django based the other is node based

Comment: it was just an example, i have two projects one is django based the other is node based. they both run well in other machines. and i can't even publish mqtt message nor receive. the problem is in my computer, i can't send messages to any server, i had to mention that the internet connection works just fine and didn't have problem with internet navigation. i guess it has something todo with my windows configuration or the process that are running on it.